# get_terms() How many is TOO many?

Tags: taxonomy, terms

Working on revamping a plugin of mine when I noticed that `wp_count_terms()` is not reflecting the same number as a call to `count( get_terms() )` with the same $args passed. I'm pretty sure this is a bug in WordPress and I'll submit a trac ticket in a little bit.

I wanted to get a solid working solution, so I ended up just making one call to `get_terms()` and then using `count()` on the array to get the count. My question is: "How many terms can be returned without slowing everything down". It's possible that there could be scaling issues here where there are a lot of terms in a taxonomy, but how many is TOO many? 1,000? 10,000?  Just looking for a ballpark here.

Comment: This got anywhere since? `wp_count_terms()` is essentially thin wrapper on top of `get_terms()` so it seems strange. Code examples?

Comment: No better solution yet. May need to put in a ticket for 3.3. At least in 3.1, wp_count_terms() will force a few parameters which throws the counts off for certain custom queries like the one I was using. It works well for the core queries though.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ad slowing down)

Lame answer: depends on your server and stuff.

#### Ad possible bug)

`wp_count_terms();` is a level "above" `get_terms();` and therefore has values like `'hide_empty'` and `'fields'` already set. I'd say: diff your `$args` against those predefinied by `wp_count_term();`. The later function does nothing than calling the `get_terms()` at it's end.

Comment: The "Lame answer" is what I'm looking for. Could you please expand on this? I'm aware that wp_count_terms() calls get_terms(). There is no diff between the args passed to both functions. With the "fields" argument set to "count" get_terms() will build an optimized query that (I believe) will be faster/less-memory-intense than a direct call to get_terms()

Comment: I'm not good at server related stuff, so this answer will stay "lame". Sry :)

Comment: @mfields A starting point would be to do a manual sql query like `echo $GLOBALS['wpdb']->query( 'EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM '.$GLOBALS['wpdb']->prefix.'terms' );` to see what the table offers. Then maybe inspect the indices and add some if this would benefit from it. If you got a MyISAM DB table (and not InnoDB), then maybe you could do something like `PACK_KEYS=1` to speed it up, as reading is what the terms are mostly used on the viewer facing side.

Comment: Please post a code sample. I think @kaiser is on to something with the hide_empty param.